# TypeScript: JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working with React 16.2.0, TypeScript 2.7.1, and *any* is not allowed as a type.

The main component:

```
// index.js

import * as React from 'react'
import Page from './page'
import i18n from '../i18n'

import PageContent from '../components/pageContent'
import withMoreInfo from '../hoc/withMoreInfo'

class Home extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <Page title={ i18n.t('home.title') }>
      <PageContent />
    </Page>
  }
}

export default withMoreInfo(Home)
```

The hoc file:

```
import * as React from 'react'

export default function withMoreInfo<T> (Wrapped: T) {
  return class WithMoreInfo extends React.Component<{ asPath: string }> {
    static async getInitialProps ({ asPath }: { asPath: string }) {
      return { asPath }
    }

    render () {
      const { asPath } = this.props
      const language = asPath.indexOf('/ro') === 0 ? 'ro' : 'en'
      return <Wrapped language={ language } pathname={ asPath } />
    }
  }
}
```

I can't solve this error: `error #TS2604: JSX element type 'Wrapped' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

[image]

Any hint is very much appreciated.
Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that the parameter is a constructor function and that returns a React component with the properties `language` and `pathname`

```
function withMoreInfo<T extends React.Component<{ language: string, pathname: string }, any>>(Wrapped: new (props: { language: string, pathname: string }, context?: any) => T) {
    return class WithMoreInfo extends React.Component<{ asPath: string }> {
        static async getInitialProps({ asPath }: { asPath: string }) {
            return { asPath }
        }

        render() {
            const { asPath } = this.props
            const language = asPath.indexOf('/ro') === 0 ? 'ro' : 'en'
            return <Wrapped language={language} pathname={asPath} />
        }
    }
}
// The component must have properties language and pathname and only those
class Home extends React.Component<{ language: string, pathname: string }> {
    render() {
        return <div />
    }
}

export default withMoreInfo(Home)
```

In your original version when you invoke `withMoreInfo(Home)`, `T` would have indeed been a react component, however you could have just as well invoked `withMoreInfo(1)` since `T` was in no way constrained. The generic function must be correct for any type that is passed to it, so the compiler considered `T` as being possibly anything and so it could reliably say nothing about it.
The solution is to let the compiler know, that the `Wrapped` parameter is a constructor of a react component, namely any react component `T` that has as properties `{ language: string, pathname: string }`. A constructor function has a similar signature declaration to a regular function, just with the `new` keyword, hence `new (props: { language: string, pathname: string }, context?: any) => T`

Comment: Titian, thank you so much for your reply! I've been searching for that answer for a while and haven't seen any article or piece of code with this setup. This is precious.

**Question 1**: I was expecting "T" to be of type Home (which extends React.Component). It's counter-intuitive to have to redeclare the extension. Can you explain why or give me a hint/link where to read about this?

**Question 2**: you use the "new" instruction without a name. Does TS infer it from *<T extends React.Component<MoreInfo>>*? That's not very clear for me.

Thanks again for your precious help.
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Putting an answer here because it is relevant to the error in general.

I was missing `new` inside the type definition.

`some-js-component.d.ts` file:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class SomeJSXComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
    new (props: any, context?: any)
}
```

and inside the `tsx` file where I was trying to import the untyped component:

```
import SomeJSXComponent from 'some-js-component'

...inside render()
   return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <SomeJSXComponent withProps={asdf} />
        </React.Fragment>
   );
```