# JSX element type 'Wrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use reactnode for my ExampleWrapper

```
<ExampleWrapper {...rest} ref={fRef}>
        {elements.map((key) => (
          <Element
            $duration={duration}
            $height={height}
           
          />
        ))}
      </ExampleWrapper>
```

But I am getting the error below like `JSX element type 'Wrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)`

Can you please let me know what wrongi am doing here.

Comment: I think this might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964924/typescript-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call-signatures